# One to Many to join with latest record and filter issue in EF core 2.1

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I had a service method that was working fine in version core 2.0 to return all products that are available or soon available for rents.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Rent> Rents { get; set; }
}

public class Rent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    }
```

The service to list all the products that are:

- Available for rent
- Available **soon** for rent (where (EndDate-DateTime.Now).TotalDays<=10)

  The service is as below:

  ```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetProductsForRent()
    {
       var innerquery = from e in _repository.Rents
              group e by e.ProductId into g
              select new
              {
                  ProductId = g.Key,
                  CreationTime = g.Max(r => r.CreationTime)
              };

          var query = from d in _repository.Products
          join h in innerquery on d.Id equals h.ProductId into gj
          from e in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select d;

      var availableProducts = await query.Include(r=>r.Rents).Where(y => !y.Rents.Any() 
                                                     || (y.Rents.First().EndDate - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 10).ToListAsync();

      return availableProducts;
  }
  ```

This method used to work just fine until the project is upgraded to [core 2.1 form core 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/30/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-1/)

I have checked EF core 2.1 announcement and I can see the note below:

> Before version 2.1, in EF Core the GroupBy LINQ operator was always be
>   evaluated in memory.

I am not sure whether this translation causing the problem but I get the error message :

> System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.    at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , ValueBuffer )    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.ProjectionShaper.TypedProjectionShaper`3.Shape(QueryContext queryContext, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.CompositeShaper.TypedCompositeShaper`5.Shape(QueryContext queryContext, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.WhereEnumerableAsyncIterator`1.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.AsyncSelectEnumerable`2.AsyncSelectEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at '' in 'codelocation':line 141    at Abp.Threading.InternalAsyncHelper.AwaitTaskWithPostActionAndFinallyAndGetResult[T](Task`1 actualReturnValue, Func`1 postAction, Action`1 finalAction)    at Abp.Threading.InternalAsyncHelper.AwaitTaskWithFinallyAndGetResult[T](Task`1 actualReturnValue, Action`1 finalAction)    at '' in 'codelocation' 74 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

**My question:** Is there any way to simplify the service query (preferable in lambda expressions) to return all available products for renting?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `innerQuery`? From what I see you are `left join`-ing to it, but then do not use any field from it.

Comment: @IvanStoev I do use it when the navigation properties are loaded. I have added Include(r=>r.Rents). This way the innerquery helps to load only the latest record as in the Rents list. I am not sure this is the right wqay though. But I will definitely be using the fields from Rent latest rent object if exists.

Comment: One of the problem in your code is that you are using `||` in `where` loop. So even if `Rents` is null, it will check the other condition which has `First` function over `Rents`. That's may be the reason of your exception. I don't think it's issue due to dot net core upgrade.

Comment: Looks like you should cast `g.Max(r => r.CreationTime)` to a nullable datetime.